# Create nested barplot for each month of multiple years

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframes df with monthly data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "2020-01-01",
            "2020-02-01",
            "2020-03-01",
            "2021-01-01",
            "2021-02-01",
            "2021-03-01",
        ],
        "cat1": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"],
        "cat2": ["hhh", "kkk", "lll", "hhh", "kkk", "lll"],
        "cat3": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "xxx", "yyy", "opoiuo"],
        "count": [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)
```

I would like to plot 3 barcharts:

- with "cat1" in the x-axis and the "count" in the y-axis
- with "cat1"+"cat2" in the x-axis and the "count" in the y-axis
- with "cat1"+"cat2"+"cat3" in the x-axis and the "count" in the y-axis

Since I have data from multiple years I would like to have 2 bars per year_month , one red and one blue, to compare the values from last year_month to this year_month . I think this is called a nested barplot?

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RARzx.jpg

So far I have (e.g. df2 with "cat1":

```
ax = (
    df.set_index(
        [
            "cat1",
        ]
    )
    .plot(kind="bar", grid=True, rot=90, figsize=(20, 5))
)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(
        np.round(p.get_height(), decimals=2),
        (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 3.0, p.get_height()),
        ha="center",
        va="center",
        xytext=(0, 6),
        textcoords="offset points",
    )
plt.show()
```

but that only works with 1 year, I can't seem to get a nested barplot?

I have pandas, matplotlib and seaborn installed. Whatever is easier for the plotting but preferably only one tool for all plots if possible.

How can I do such nested barplots with a pandas dataframe? Examples I've found use lists and numpy + matplotlib but not dataframes.

Comment: This seems like *a lot* of questions for a single Stack Overflow thread.

Comment: @HenryEcker True, removed 2 dataframes/questions.